# RewriteRule of htaccess file gives a 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, url

I've the problem that my .htaccess RewriteRule gives me a 404 error page no matter what I'm trying.

My files are located inside the `/df-talents` directory on the server. Inside this folder the .htaccess file is located, too.

I need a RewriteRule which redirects the URL to `/df-talents/index.html` when the actual URL  has the word "classes" included.

This is the content of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.html|.js|.css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|txt|ico|webp)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.eot|.ttf|.woff)

RewriteRule ^(.*)classes(.*)$ index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous _related_ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807164/htaccess-rewriterules-are-giving-a-404-error)? There was a lot of information in my answer to that question that could be useful to other readers and you don't appear to have applied several of the recommendations I suggested in that answer to your rule above. (?)

Comment: What is `/classes`? Does this relate to anything on the filesystem? You don't appear to have tested this properly... as there is obviously something else going on... `/classes` (and `/classes/<anything>`) results in an Apache 404, but `/classes<anything>` (or `/<anything>classes`) appears to get rewritten to `index.html` (and your JS script then strips the URL-path)?

Comment: `Classes` does not relate to anything on the filesystem.  The informations in the url are just giving the parameters for the scripts. My question is why the htaccess doesn't rewrites the url as expected? What could be a problem here?
I tried all of your solutions from the last question but sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: "`Classes` does not ..." - "Classes" or "classes"? The problem is not with the rule you posted. As I mentioned above, there would seem to be something else going on here, that relates specifically to the initial path segment `/classes` (all lowercase). The rule you posted already performs a case-insensitive match (as denoted by the `NC` flag), however `/Classes` (mixed case) and `/classes` (lowercase) behave differently for some reason. `/Classes` appears to be rewritten, but `/classes` results in a 404. Why?

Comment: You've tagged the question `php` - are you using PHP here?